# How to disable emacs here document completion

Tags: bash, emacs, autocomplete

When editing a bash script file with emacs, and trying to enter `<<<`, at the second `<` emacs insert a template for a here document, like in the following example:

```
<<EOF

EOF
```

This is not the desired output, because I would enter a literal `<<<`.

For the moment I resort to entering `< < <`, and then deleting spaces, but I prefer to being allowed to enter it directly.

Comment: Not that I care too much, but It would be nice to leave a comment for a downvote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is actually no need for Tom 's custom `my-disable-here-document` function rebinding the keys. This feature can be enabled and disabled with `sh-electric-here-document-mode`:

```
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (sh-electric-here-document-mode -1)))
```

(It can also be toggled for the active buffer via `M-x sh-electric-here-document-mode`.)

Comment: Also: `sh-mode-hook` didn't work for me, but `sh-set-shell-hook` did.

Answer (score 6):

Bind `<` to `self-insert-command` in bash mode and then it will insert only the character.

By default it is bound to `sh-maybe-here-document` when in bash mode and that function does the auto-insertion.

Here is a way to rebound the key:

```
(add-hook 'sh-set-shell-hook 'my-disable-here-document)

(defun my-disable-here-document ()
  (local-set-key "<" 'self-insert-command))
```

Comment: Can you please give some more information on what to exactly insert in the init file? Sorry, but I am a beginner emacs's user.

Comment: I added a simple example to my answer. It disables the automatic insertion in every kind of shell, not just bash, but probaly that's what you want anyway.

Comment: This solution does not work anymore (tested on emacs 24.3), because `<` is bound to `self-insert-command` by default.

Answer (score 2):

If the only reason you want to disable the *here-doc* behaviour is that it prevents you from inserting a *here-string* <<<, then binding `C-<` to a function which contains `(insert "<<<")` will work, and still allow the auto *here-doc* template

```
(defun my-here-string() 
  "Insert <<< (eg. for a bash here-string)" 
  (interactive)
  (insert "<<<"))
(global-set-key (kbd  "C-<") 'my-here-string)
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting solution, but I still prefer @Tom's answer, because I consider that completion wrong for a bash script file.

Answer (score 2):

I enter `<<<` as <kbd>M-3</kbd><kbd><</kbd> in the shell mode.

Answer (score 1):

Type <kbd><</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> <kbd><</kbd>

Comment: It is shorter than my workaround, and perhaps useful for other situations too, but not exactly what I was looking for. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at: http://web.mit.edu/dosathena/sandbox/emacs-19.28/lisp/sh-script.el
I came up with this solution:

```
;; disable the automatic EOF generation in Shell Mode
(defvar sh-use-prefix nil
  "If non-nil when loading, `$' and `<' will be  C-c $  and  C-c < .")
(defvar sh-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (if sh-use-prefix "\C-c<" "<")
      (local-set-key "<" 'self-insert-command))
   map)
  "Keymap used in Shell-Script mode.")
```